# Why the Value of form.AddField won't accept string

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I want to send some data to my server..
so i make this C# code

```
IEnumerator SaveAllPlayerPrefs(string[] parms)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        form.AddField("bone" , value);

        WWW webRequest = new WWW(db_url + "SaveAllPlayerPref.php", form);

        yield return webRequest;
    }
```

And i have php code for recieving that

```
<?php

    $sql_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("no DB Connection");

    mysql_select_db("example") or die ("DB not found");

    $bone = $_POST['bone'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO save_game (bone) VALUES ($bone);");

    mysql_close($sql_connect);
?>
```

The problem is when i try this code it works nicely, but it when the value is still int.
when i change the value into string type, it can't send to database, and my unity is crash,

later i try to change the value to char, i try to send

> 'a'
>   but when i do that in database its not saving 'a' instead its saving 97, the ASCI value..

I dont't understand what's wrong with this, and in my database in server, i set the value is varchar(100)..

please help me and thx before :)

Comment: What is the type of `value`?

Comment: i want it to  be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [WWWForm.AddField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html) states that you can only use an `int` as a second parameter so it behaves correctly and a [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) is actaully a single character and a *16-bit numeric (ordinal) value* so it gets casted to an int.

```
AddField(fieldName: string, i: int): void;
```

or you can try the second method with encoding so that you can pass a `string` value.

```
AddField(fieldName: string, value: string, e: Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8): void;
```

I'm not sure about the PHP part but I think you may need quotes around the `$bone`

```
"INSERT INTO save_game (bone) VALUES ('$bone');"
```

Comment: yeah and i must input System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 in last parameter too :)